# Error handling: Cannot convert type in Swift 2

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

How do I catch an error if a function argument is not of the correct type?

**Function:**

```
func returnBool(someBool: Bool) -> Bool {
    return someBool
}
```

**Given:**

returnBool("not a Bool")

**Result:**

"Cannot convert value of type..."

**What I want to see:**

false, nil or the like + no error

Comment: well, you tell the compiler you are expecting a Bool and then you try to pass in a String - but that simply does not work! If you want to be able to pass in a String, you have to change the type of `someBool`

Comment: that's not the question I asked. in python it's easy to catch an error before it executes and return whatever you want. i'm asking if I can do that in Swift.

Comment: @GaryCooper see my updated question, maybe it can help you

Comment: This is a compiler error. You can't catch it. Debug it!

Comment: That is exactly what you are asking, you have to read up on ***types*** - a pretty fundamental concept.

Answer (score 0):

Compiler won't allow you to do like this way. If you want to check some param, which can be any object, then use `AnyObject` and check it with `guard` statement:

```
func returnBool(someBool: AnyObject) -> Bool {
    guard someBool is Bool else { return false }
    return true
}
let result1 = returnBool("test") // false
let result2 = returnBool(false) // true
let result3 = returnBool(1) // true
```

or

```
func returnBool(someBool: AnyObject) -> Bool? {
    guard someBool is Bool else { return nil }
    return someBool as? Bool
}
let result1 = returnBool("test") // nil
let result2 = returnBool(false) // false
let result3 = returnBool(1) // true
```

Comment: be careful !!!!!  to be able to compile your examples, you need to import Foundation and let the compiler to create non Swift objects inherited from NSObject, which are able to be cast to AnyObject.Type. this can lead to lot of misunderstandings and potential bugs.